# Direect angle extraction from quaternion

Tags: trigonometry, rotations, quaternions

please forgive my lack of background in math's, but i need to clear up a doubt i have about quaternion and the rotation they express.

my goal is to extract the angle (specifically pitch and roll) the sensor is giving me from a quaternion.
I need the angles around its own axis rather than a fixed frame.

given a unit quaterion q = a + bi + cj + dk.
Using :

$$
pitch = 2sin^{-1}(b) \\
roll = 2sin^{-1}(c) \\
yaw = 2sin^{-1}(d)
$$

i can extract the angles but only when the sensor is not rotated around yaw from the starting angle.
when i start rotating yaw, everything get wonky.

i am sure i am missing something important, but i need some easy-to-understand tips to get moving.

I have also noticed that if i multiply the rotation quaternion to its conjugate i have a "zeroing" effect on the output.

Thanks

Comment: The answer will very much depend on the **rotation order** that was used (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). Do you know which one was used?

Comment: Here's also (a bit long, I admit) discussion on a similar question. Please read my answer, it should clarify the computations quite much: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273597/euler-angles-quaternion-and-mobile-device-rotation/3273621#3273621

Comment: I have searched quite extensively inside the sensor datasheet (BNO080 from Ceva-DSP) but nowhere is clearly said what rotation order was used. I have made some tests with euler conversion, and found that ZYX scheme fit correctly.

Comment: Just to be extra-clear. Given a certain Quaterion, needing rotations around its own axis, i can just go with the atan/asin/atan conversion to extract angles, or in this case i need to manipulate an intermediate quaternion to work with ?

Comment: What do you mean by "angles around its own axis"? What is "it" in this case?

Comment: its own, is around the axis of the sensor itself, for example, with euler conversion i have seen that when i tilt the sensor 90° forward, roll and yaw swaps. Trying to clarify more... when the sensor is at rest, the axis that i use to extract roll is "parallel" to the ground, if i tilt forward 90° the very same axis as before is perpendicular to the ground. The angle i "want" is always around that rotated axis. Hope that helped

Comment: So do I understand correctly that you want only the roll angle (using standard Euler angles)?

Comment: roll and pitch really... i have used roll as an example.

Comment: Try the following formulas and report back if it worked:
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\tan{\phi}  &=& \frac{2\left(p_0 p_3 - p_1 p_2 \right)}{p_0^2 + p_1^2 - p_2^2 - p_3^2}    \\
\sin{\theta}&=& 2 \left( p_0 p_2 + p_1 p_3 \right)       \\
\tan{\psi}  &=& \frac{  2 \left( p_0 p_1 - p_2 p_3 \right)   }{ p_0^2 - p_1^2 - p_2^2 + p_3^2   }
\end{array}
\right.$$
In this equation, $q_0$ through $q_3$ are the quaternion components; with your notation $a=q_0, b=q_1, c=q_2, d=q_3$. Note that to take the inverse tangent, I recommend the "atan2" function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

Comment: The equation that I displayed is for the $zyx$ rotation order. If the equation doesn't work, you can try switching around the indices and try to find the correct combination.

Comment: I am already using that very same combination... but one thing that i am noticing is that when i pitch 90° forward, roll and yaw swaps... rotation on the same axis that when i was leveled gives me roll, now (when pitched 90 degrees) represents yaw. i have used formulas founds on this site (http://bediyap.com/programming/convert-quaternion-to-euler-rotations) and tried all the combinations possibile. some won't work, other seems to work, but in the end all suffer of the same "swap" that i mentioned above.